# Can Perl print code as plain text?

Tags: perl

I want Perl to print the following string:

```
'<span><%= blah %></span>'
```

But seems Perl tries to parse it, because of the `%` and `>`

is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What are you seeing that makes you think Perl is trying to parse those characters?

Comment: Are you possibly using Mojolicious? It looks like you are using an HTML templating engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl doesn't attempt to interpolate variables if you use single quotes. If your string contains single quotes, use [q](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators):

```
print q{'<span><%= blah %></span>'};
```

Answer (score 3):

All of

```
'\'<span><%= blah %></span>\''

q{'<span><%= blah %></span>'}

"'<span><%= blah %></span>'"
```

and numerous others produce the string

```
'<span><%= blah %></span>'
```

Neither "`%`" nor "`>`" are special to the single-quoted operator and the double-quoted operator. Since no character is special to `print`, you can use any of the following to actually output the string:

```
print '\'<span><%= blah %></span>\'';

print q{'<span><%= blah %></span>'};

print "'<span><%= blah %></span>'";
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the quotes in the question are actually part of the string or just part of a string literal. It doesn't really affect the question, though. Just remove them if you don't want them.

Comment: `%` (but not `>`) is special to `printf`. Were you perhaps using `printf`?

Comment: this is probably the case, I can't get Perl to give any error except by using `printf`.